# Midnight in UTC time zone with unix timestamp

Tags: math, unix-timestamp

I was looking for a numeric representation for a date and unix time for midnight (in UTC) seems to be reasonable choice for that. However, as I'm not sure in my math skills, so is

```
date = date - date % (24 * 60 * 60);
```

where `date` is unix timestamp, the way to do that? Is there any simpler method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your formula is a perfectly good way of doing that. Another way of accomplishing the same thing is:

```
date = (date / 86400) * 86400;
```

It may be worth noting that the above formula assumes integer (truncating) division. Also, I feel that `86400` is a sufficiently commonly used constant that it can appear in source code without additional comment.

Answer (score 1):

Desired language/libraries?

I'll assume C with standard UNIX libraries.

[`time.h`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ctime) would be perfectly suitable.

```
#include <time.h>

struct tm date_tm;
time_t date;

localtime_r(NULL, &date_tm);
date_tm.tm_sec = 0;
date_tm.tm_min = 0;
date_tm.tm_hour = 0;

date = mktime(&date_tm);
```

I suppose the roundabout to-string/from-string method would work too, but I wouldn't recommend it.  (`%F` and `%Z` should be required by C99 and/or some POSIX or SUS specification.)

```
#define DATE_FORMAT "%F %Z"  /* yyyy-mm-dd t-z */

char date_str[15];
struct tm date_tm;
time_t date;

localtime_r(NULL, &date_tm);
strftime(date_str, sizeof(date_str), DATE_FORMAT, &date_tm);
strptime(date_str, DATE_FORMAT, &date_tm);

date = mktime(&date_tm);
```

---

Hmm, I didn't notice at first that you want UTC.  Since one UNIX day is guaranteed to always be 86400 UNIX seconds in UNIX time, I don't see any problem with your original solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just use strtotime without a time portion.

Comment: That's assuming you are using PHP. You can also use `strtotime('midnight')`